# how to loop nested json and display data into it. in angular 8

Tags: javascript, json, angular

i have below nested json which i was getting from api.

Comment: Why, with [*ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) of course

Comment: bt i dnt know how to iterate json data and display in html..

Comment: ...with *ngFor. That's its job. I even gave you the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below :
   Here I have considered that your policy units array has only object inside it so have used policy_units[0].

```
 <div class="bx--col-lg-3 bx--col-md-3 text-div">
        <div class="text" *ngFor="let providers of Details['policy_units'][0]['providers'];">{{ providers }} </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bx--col-lg-3 bx--col-md-3 text-div">
        <div *ngFor="let edit_authorised_role of Details['policy_units'][0]['schema']['edit_authorised_roles'];">
        <div class="text">{{ edit_authorised_role }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bx--col-lg-3 bx--col-md-3 text-div">
        <div *ngFor="let delete_authorised_role of Details['policy_units'][0]['schema']['delete_authorised_roles'];">
        <div class="text">{{ delete_authorised_role }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="bx--col-lg-3 bx--col-md-3 text-div">
    <div class="text">Details['policy_units'][0]['schema']['provider_push']</div>
</div>"
```

OR

If you want to iterate over policy units array in you json, you can do this below :

```
<div *ngFor="let policy_unit of Details['policy_units']>

<div class="bx--col-lg-3 bx--col-md-3 text-div">
        <div class="text" *ngFor="let providers of policy_unit['providers'];">{{ providers }} </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bx--col-lg-3 bx--col-md-3 text-div">
        <div *ngFor="let edit_authorised_role of policy_unit['schema']['edit_authorised_roles'];">
        <div class="text">{{ edit_authorised_role }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bx--col-lg-3 bx--col-md-3 text-div">
        <div *ngFor="let delete_authorised_role of policy_unit['schema']['delete_authorised_roles'];">
        <div class="text">{{ delete_authorised_role }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="bx--col-lg-3 bx--col-md-3 text-div">
    <div class="text">policy_units['schema']['provider_push']</div>
</div>"
</div>
```

Comment: if there is no data {{ edit_authorised_role }} then how to add text no data inside this..i mean or condition here

Comment: Just use an ngIF condition , if length of edit_authorised_role is 0, statically print ‘no data’

Comment: bt i am gettin error in console for let providers of Details['policy_units'][0]['providers'];
details is undefined